# Elasticsearch term facet not showing negative terms

Tags: elasticsearch, faceted-search, facet

I am using elastic search term facets, My field contains some negative values but the facet is ignoring the negative sign

following is the facet query

**http://myserver.com:9200/index/type/_search**

Get/Post body

```
{
  "facets" : {
    "school.id" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "school.id",
        "size" : 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "took": 281,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "facets": {
        "school.id": {
            "_type": "terms",
            "missing": 302,
            "total": 4390,
            "other": 0,
            "terms": [
                {
                    "term": "1113515007867355135",
                    "count": 4390
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The actual value of id is **-1113515007867355135**, am I doing something wrong or do I need to pass anything to include negative sign (stemming issue)?

Comment: posted on elasticsearch group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/FeObbeT1eok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from [Elasticsearch Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/FeObbeT1eok). Need to update the mapping of the field

Possible Solution:

Update the mapping and use

**"index":"analyzed","analyzer" : "keyword"**

or

**"index": "not_analyzed"**

Answer (score 2):

The negative sign is a special character in Lucene (and ElasticSearch).

While indexing and searching you need to [escape it](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters).

Try adding a `\` before the `-` character in your index, that should bring it up in the facet as well.

Comment: Thanks for the link but It is coming in facets results without -ve sign, where to add escaping for facets (query body)?

Comment: You need to escape even while creating the index. I.e. before storing the values in elastic search index, these need to be escaped.

Comment: Adding a \ before the negative sign in the search query solved my problem. Thanks!